# How to make infrastructure as code using a manifest.jps file in Jelastic platform?

Tags: microservices, jelastic, infrastructure

I have a project which contains 12 microservices built with Java Spring Boot using Docker. I also have 3 web clients built in React and Angular that consume the APIs. Now I'm trying to deploy the whole project to one server first, and I'm thinking of AWS JElastic platform that I'm trying out right now.

My microservices use Java, Spring Boot, Postgres, MySQL, Redis docker images,and the web clients use docker Node image.
So to start I create a new environnement from my Jelastic admin panel and installed the Docker engine. I now want to add my required languages Java, node, Postgres and all that my microservices need to run in the Jelastic environnement. Searching on internet I've seen that I should write a manifest.jps file to create my infrastructure by code, and so far I've come up with a manifest.jsp file.

If the main purpose of the manifest.jps file is to help automate my infrastructure creation and configuration by code, how can I then load it to my environnement to make my project work ? Should I write a manifest.jps file for each of the microservice of my project? How can I deploy this kind of project to a single server on Jelastic platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with a team where we use the Jelastic platform. If I'm right with what you want, you have a set of backend microservices et frontend apps, and you want to deploy them togheter to the Jelastic. You also said that your microservices are dockerized along with the frontend apps. If it is that then you are good to get deployed easier.

> Searching on internet I've seen that I should write a manifest.jps
> file to create my infrastructure by code, and so far I've come up with
> a manifest.jsp file.

I would answer this part first and say that the manisfest.jps file is not mandatory as you could also manualy add your **programing languages**, **database engines** and project requirements from clicks.
But If you want the manifest.jps file, you write it in root folder, push it to your gihub or gitlab account and from there copy the **raw** url to your Jelastic platform. You do that in the "Import" button and after the dialog box is popuped choose URL and paste your raw github url there, and then click "Import". Its all setup.

> If the main purpose of the manifest.jps file is to help automate my
> infrastructure creation and configuration by code, how can I then load
> it to my environnement to make my project work ? Should I write a
> manifest.jps file for each of the microservice of my project? How can
> I deploy this kind of project to a single server on Jelastic platform?

You only write one manisfest.jps file and it will create your environnement for all the microservices that use the dependencies specified in .jps file.
You can load it from the github url, or import the build.zip for the frontend apps.
These are a basic ways to start with jelastic.

Comment: I use to deploy my solutions to VPS, this is my first foray to the cloud providers. Thank you so much, I understand the changes in deployments